# Is it safe to use foundation classes in +load?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-category

I have a class `Persistent`, which needs to be archivable, but can change its name. NSKeyedArchiver provides `+setClassName:` method to use custom class name during archiving and unarchiving. Can I perform class-name mapping in `+load` method? Are there any gotchas?

```
@interface Persistent : NSObject <NSCoding>
@end
@implementation
+ (void)load {
   [NSKeyedArchiver setClassName:@"class" forClass:self];
}
...
@end
```

Comment: You need more courage than me to implement +load. Courage isn't necessarily a good thing for a programmer. +load or +initialize is something I'd keep my hands off. One reason is the fun that you will have when moving to Swift :-)

Comment: Related: [+\[NSObject load\] and +initialize: what do they do?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13326435) and see also a relevant tidbit from bbum here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4671741/603977